# Get name of class from class type in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

Given a class type, I'd like to get its name and print it to console. I have access to the class type but not an instance.

```
class Foo:
  pass

def print_class_names(klass):
   print(klass.__some_dunder?__) # don't know how to do this

print_class_name(Foo) # would like this to print "Foo"
```

Bonus:
I would also like to access inherited types and generic type, so, for example, if I have `list[Foo]` I could access "list" and "Foo" as separate strings.

I can directly print the class like `print(Foo)` but that gives me `<class '__main__.Student'>` and I'd like to avoid string manipulation if possible.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to see ```Student``` rather than ```<class '__main__.Student'>```?

Comment: It's very important to understand, `list[str]` **is not a type**. `list` is a type. `list[str]` is a type annotation. Anyway, given an actual type (i.e. a class) then you just want `klass.__name__`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `list[str]` is an expression whose value is an instance of `types.GenericAlias`. It behaves much like `list` at runtime, for example, `list[str]()` returns an empty list, the same as `list` itself.

Comment: If `klass` is a `GenericAlias`, it looks like the underlying type is `klass.mro()[0]` and the "argument(s)" are available from `klass.__args__`. I suspect this is somewhat fragile, though.

Comment: @chepner yeah, you want to use the function in `typing`, so `typing.get_args` and `typing.get_origin`

Comment: Ah, thanks. If I had noticed they existed, I had certainly never looked at what they were for.

Comment: `__name__` works for my purposes, thanks all